# WordPress/JS - Price depends on the product

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wp condition which displays me the price of the products.

```
if (empty($sales_price)) {
            echo '<span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'.$regular_price.'&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></span> </span>';
        } else {
            echo '<span class="price"><del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'.$regular_price.'&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'.$sales_price.'&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></span></ins></span>';
        }
```

Each product has several variations and different prices. 
My problem is that prices do not change when changing options in the select box. 
I tried to add JS in different ways but nothing wanted to reload my price. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, PHP + JS should do the trick, you can locate and set a php script to respond to AJAX Request on WP.
Though, I'd link you an answer i gave a few time ago for a different question, but it should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45490613/6654533

What you're supposed to do with this method is the following:

- Use javascript to take the value of the select when the `change` event is fired and send an AJAX POST request as shown by the answer posted above;
- Use the AJAX success callback to render, what your PHP returns
- Use PHP to retrieve the price of the item, based on the param you posted;

Hope it helps!